# Struggling on finding the missing value in the cumulative distribution function:

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

For some c > $0$, the cumulative distribution function of a continuous random variable X is given by:

$$
F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \le0 \\ cx(x+1) & \text{if } 0 \lt x <1 \\ 1 & \text{if } x \ge 1\end{cases}
$$

Show that $c = 1/2 $

I know that by differentiating  $cx(x+1)$ and equating to 1, I obtain the cumulative distribution function but I don't know how to eliminate $x$ after differentiating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to remember the properties of the CDF. One of them states that

$$F_X(+\infty)=1$$

In your case you have

$$F_X(1)=1$$

that is $2c=1$

$$c=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use the fact that

$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t) dt$$

This will give you the probability distribution function

Then use the fact that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx = 1$$